# Repeated-measure Correlation Analysis | Correlation per Participant

Tags: r, correlation, t-test

I have a data-set based on a within-subject design. So we have a data-set with repeated-measures with 3 different variables. Thus, the associations between the variables is supposed to be independent between subjects. So the correlation need to calculated on an individual level.

I would like to do the following:

Step 1) Create a table with the correlation of all 3 variables (value_01*value_02, value_01*value_03, value_02*value_03) for each participant.

Step 2) Perform a one-sided t-test against zero

So, let's say we have a data-set with like this:

```
df <- read.table(text = 'ID condition value_01 value_02 value_03
    01 A 7 13 22
    01 B 5 20 18
    01 C 6 60 23
    01 D 8 11 22
    02 B 7 17 18
    02 C 9 18 20
    02 D 5 7 23
    02 A 7 7 22
    03 C 8 12 20
    03 D 3 11 22
    03 A 8 15 22'
    03 B 9 118 25')
```

What we are looking for is a correlation table like this:

```
ID value_01*value_02 value_01*value_03 value_01*value_02*value_03
01 0.56 0.37 0.28
02 0.4 5 0.45 0.35
03 0.34 0.36 0.23
```

I tried out to calculate the correlation like this:

```
 library(dplyr)
subset <- df %>%
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    summarise(
    Value_01_02 = cor(value_01, value_02, method = "pearson"),
    Value_01_03 = cor(value_01, value_03, method = "pearson"),
    Value_02_03 = cor(value_02, value_03, method = "pearson")
    )

View(subset)
```

But the output is wrong, since it only calculates one correlation coefficiant for each combination of variables. The wrong results look like this:

```
ID value_01*value_02 value_01*value_03 value_02*value_03
01 0.24 0.13 0.33
```

Does anybody know how I can fix this?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly use [rmcorr](https://lmarusich.github.io/rmcorr/index.html) :

```
library(dplyr)                 
library(rmcorr)

cor <- rmcorr_mat(participant = ID,
                  variables = c('value_01',
                                'value_02',
                                'value_03'),
                  dataset = df,
                  CI.level = 0.95)

cor
#> 
#> Repeated measures correlation matrix
#> 
#>            value_01  value_02   value_03
#> value_01 1.00000000 0.3443627 0.09101661
#> value_02 0.34436266 1.0000000 0.48127980
#> value_03 0.09101661 0.4812798 1.00000000

cor$summary
#>   measure1 measure2 df   rmcorr.r    lowerCI   upperCI    p.vals effective.N
#> 1 value_01 value_02  8 0.34436266 -0.3642375 0.8004381 0.3298600          10
#> 2 value_01 value_03  8 0.09101661 -0.5713518 0.6815838 0.8025423          10
#> 3 value_02 value_03  8 0.48127980 -0.2128438 0.8525584 0.1590385          10
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: But in this case I still don't have a table with all three correlation for EVERY PARTICIPANT.

Comment: I also tried to use rmcorr. This is not the output I was going for.

Answer (score 1):

One problem in your code was the missing header=TRUE part. Also you had some ' before the last line

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


df <- read.table(text = 'ID condition value_01 value_02 value_03
    01 A 7 13 22
    01 B 5 20 18
    01 C 6 60 23
    01 D 8 11 22
    02 B 7 17 18
    02 C 9 18 20
    02 D 5 7 23
    02 A 7 7 22
    03 C 8 12 20
    03 D 3 11 22
    03 A 8 15 22
    03 B 9 118 25', header=TRUE)


#See df
print(df)
```

After that, the following code:

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(
    Value_01_02 = cor(value_01, value_02, method = "pearson"),
    Value_01_03 = cor(value_01, value_03, method = "pearson"),
    Value_02_03 = cor(value_02, value_03, method = "pearson")
  )
```

Gives me the following output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
     ID Value_01_02 Value_01_03 Value_02_03
  <int>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
1     1      -0.415       0.640       0.379
2     2       0.739      -0.552      -0.885
3     3       0.512       0.239       0.893
```

See Screenshot:

[image: A screenshot of the exact same output]

Comment: If I use this code I still don't receive a repeated measure correlation matrix. So I copied your code with the example data. R gives me the following output: `Value_01_02 Value_01_03 Value_02_03
1   0.3183274   0.0937091   0.5363472`

Comment: So I really wonder how you received this output

Comment: Just tryed it again. R 4.2.3 gives me exactly that output (I will add an screenshot to the origional post). Maybe you can try a clear environment and reinstall the packages? Maybe you have also loaded other packages? You might want to try: "df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(ID) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise("

Comment: Now it worked. Thank you very much. I indeed had several other packages loaded which I had used before.